# Not able to update data in update page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on updating gridview value by sending gridview values to other page. Here, I am able to update category dropdown list value and image file only. I am not able to update textbox values.

Here is my code..

Update Product Code:

```
 protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int productId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ProductID"]);

        Product product = new Product();

        product.ProductID = productId;
        product.ProductName = TitleTextBox.Text;
        product.Description = DescriptionTextBox.Text;
        product.ItemsInSet = Convert.ToInt32(SetTextBox.Text);
        product.UnitPriceOwner = Convert.ToInt32(UnitResellerTextBox.Text);
        product.UnitPriceReseller = Convert.ToInt32(UnitResellerTextBox.Text);
        product.ShippingCost = Convert.ToInt32(ShipmentTextBox.Text);
        product.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(CategoryDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString());
        product.Visible = true;
        product.InOffer = false;

        if (ImageUpload.HasFile)
        {
            int length = ImageUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            product.ProductImage = new byte[length];
            ImageUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(product.ProductImage, 0, length);
        }
        else
        {
            Byte[] image;

            image = ProductBL.GetImage(productId);
            product.ProductImage = image;
        }

        ProductBL.UpdateProduct(product);
        MessageLabel.Text = "Product successfully Updated!";
    }
```

UpdateProduct() code:

```
public static void UpdateProduct(Product product)
    {
        string query = "UPDATE [Products] SET [ProductName] = @ProductName, [Description] = @Description, [ItemsInSet] = @ItemsInSet, " +
                        "[UnitPriceOwner] = @UnitPriceOwner, [UnitPriceReseller] = @UnitPriceReseller, [CategoryID] = @CategoryID, " + 
                        "[ShippingCost] = @ShippingCost, [InOffer] = @InOffer, [ProductImage] = @ProductImage, [Visible] = @Visible WHERE [ProductID] = @ProductID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = product.ProductName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", SqlDbType.Text).Value = product.Description;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemsInSet", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.ItemsInSet;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPriceOwner", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.UnitPriceOwner;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPriceReseller", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.UnitPriceReseller;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.CategoryID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShippingCost", SqlDbType.Int).Value = product.ShippingCost;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InOffer", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = product.InOffer;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visible", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = product.Visible;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = product.ProductID;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductImage", SqlDbType.Image).Value = product.ProductImage == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : product.ProductImage;

        DbUtility.UpdateDb(cmd);
    }
```

Page Load Code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int productId = 0;
        productId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ProductID"]);

        LoadProductDetails(productId);
    }

    protected void LoadProductDetails(int productId)
    {
        var product = ProductBL.GetProductById(productId);

        TitleTextBox.Text = product.ProductName;
        DescriptionTextBox.Text = product.Description;
        SetTextBox.Text = Convert.ToInt32(product.ItemsInSet).ToString();
        UnitOwnerTextBox.Text = Convert.ToInt32(product.UnitPriceOwner).ToString();
        UnitResellerTextBox.Text = Convert.ToInt32(product.UnitPriceReseller).ToString();
        ShipmentTextBox.Text = Convert.ToInt32(product.ShippingCost).ToString();
    }
```

Kindly Help me

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean you're not able to? Are you saying `MessageLabel` doesn't show the string you set it to? What does your `Page_Load()` method look like?

Comment: I am not able to update textbox values. I can change image and dropdown value.

Comment: Please Have a look at Updated code. I am getting same textbox values which i have added. In this update page, I do want change old textbox values. But, I am not able to update those texbox values in database. Not getting any error. Just not updating new values in textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load your **LoadProductDetails** in

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
//here
}
```

Comment: Additional information: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)

Comment: @Orion restart the visual studio once

Answer (score 0):

first thing always check for null condition before using Session or Query String variable to avoid any chances of getting error.
I think here you are missing to check `!IsPostback` condition that's why when you click on Update button then your updated values will be lost as your method `LoadProductDetails(productId);` called.